# How to access access gadgets.* with OpenSocial

Tags: opensocial

Is there a way to use `gadgets.*` in my JavaScript code if my content type is URL?

Comment: You have to provide more context. What are you trying to achieve? What problems are you encountering? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Proxied Content](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Proxied_Content) feature. That way you can access gadgets.* APIs from the content fetched from your own server.

```
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="My App">
    <Require feature="opensocial-0.9"/>
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content view="canvas" href="http://www.example.com/myapp/canvas/index.html">
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the OpenSocial specification (at least starting from 0.8 and later), the relative path link to JavaScript libraries of requested features should be passed in the content URL parameter. Search the OpenSocial specification for keyword 'libs' to get more information.

The problem still is that the path given in URL is relative, not absolute, and you would need to know the base URL where to append this parameter. The discussion thread [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=73bd7c3a19e79099&hl=en) suggests to use a base URL "https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/" and append the value of 'libs' as it is, but I've not successfully verified that. Code that we've used to fetch libraries for the OpenSocial gadget on iGoogle (with jQuery support) is:

```
var libsMatch = window.location.search.match(/[?&]libs=([^&]*)/);
if (libsMatch) {
    var libArray = libsMatch[1].split(",");
    $.each( libArray, function(i, val) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "http://www.google.com/ig/f/" + val,
            dataType: 'script'
        } );
    } );
}
```

NOTE, though, that not all APIs will be available this way, e.g., gadgets.io.* can't be enabled this way, others needs to be tested.